# SceneKit isResting property on SCNPhysicsBody always returns false

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I am loading a ball into an `ARSCNView` using `ARKit/SceneKit` and the ball moves along a floor plane until it comes to a stop depending on how much force I apply on the ball.

A `SCNNode` has property for detecting when the node stops moving and sets its isResting property to true by using:

```
myNode.physicsBody?.isResting
```

I have set myNode's physics body to register for resting using:

```
myNodesPhysicsBody.allowsResting = true
```

I have a function in my ball class that should detect when the ball has come to rest using:

```
func removeBowlingBallWhenNotMoving() {
        guard let bowlingBallNode = bowlingBallNode else {return}
        guard let resting = bowlingBallNode.physicsBody?.isResting else  {return} // I know I can combine these guard statements they're just here for easier debugging
        print("Resting: \(resting)") // This always returns false even when the node has visually stopped moving.
        if resting {
            performFadeOutOnBowlingBallWith(duration: Constants.bowlingBallFadeOutDuration)
        }
    }
```

Its called in **didSimulatePhysicsAtTime**:

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        bowlingBall.removeBowlingBallWhenNotMoving()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514795-isresting):

> This property’s default value is false, but SceneKit’s physics simulation may automatically set it to true if the body is not moving and not affected by any forces.

So it seems that other forces are still affecting the body.

You might be better off measuring the body's `.velocity` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514757-velocity)) to check whether it is moving or not.

Comment: Yeah thats it. I am currently actually using a working version using the velocity but I found this property isResting and thought i'd get to the bottom of why it doesn't seem to work